# How to render React components only once on startup?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I've been reading docs about performance but I can't find the answer to my question...

I have a bunch of buttons on my application that will render based on some properties but not state, parent components will never change their properties. Then I have this `onKeyDown` event handler that will listen for some keys and update another component.

My problem is that when pressing keys and updating this one component, all the other buttons will render too (observed through React dev tools for Chrome). I haven't implemented `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` on my buttons, but shouldn't React have this behavior by default? I mean, compare `this.props` with `nextProps` and if they are exactly the same, do not call `render()`?

Am I supposed to do this myself for every component that should only render once on application startup?

**EDIT:** [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) seems solve the problem... But instead of creating a new question, I'm updating this one with a related question:

**Why wouldn't the documentation recommend to have all components based on PureComponent by default?** What are the arguments against using `PureComponent` by default instead of the typical `Component`?

Comment: Do you have a performance issue or is it just for the beauty of it you would like not to have those buttons updated?

Comment: The latter, it just doesn't feel right... I know, it could just be premature optimization. But I'm just asking :)

Comment: Look at React.PureComponent instead of React.Component (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html)

Comment: @mguijarr I tried that, but the buttons still updated... Were they not supposed to?

Comment: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/820668074223353858 (and btw, stop changing the original question and go adding new ones)

Comment: FYI if you need to decide at some point whether to rerender a component or not, you can override `ShouldComponentUpdate` and decide there. For never updating it is obviously more reasonable to use the `PureComponent`. But to answer your second question really briefly: because React is mainly meant for reactive elements that do change. If you want to write static HTML, you generally don't need React to do that.

Comment: I'd wager it doesn't suggest `PureComponent` because new users will not yet understand that there is an assumption props aren't mutated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure components should solve your problem because they implement shallow prop and state comparison by default.

[Link to the docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent)

> If your React component's render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.

Comment: I had tried those (forgot to mention on the question) but React dev tools still showed all the buttons being rendered with every key press. Am I right that I should just use that class instead of the default one and nothing else needs to be done?

Comment: On a second attempt, it worked... Sorry. But this begs the question, why wouldn't the documentation recommend to have all components based on `PureComponent` by default?

Comment: @RicardoAmaral They don't implement it by default because of edge cases. Not sure what they are though. I just read it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make sure a React component is rendered only once, is by making `shouldComponentUpdate` return `false`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate = () => false

  render() {
    return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>;
  }
}
```

In the example above, even if `this.props.children` changes, the component won't render again. It will render only once, when mounted.

Comment: How can I do this in Functional Component

Comment: Check out [`React.memo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)